# Is this formula about definite integrals correct?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, calculus-of-variations

$$
F(Du(x+h) - F(Du(x))
 = \int_0^1 \int_0^t \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial s\partial s}F(sDu(x+h) + (1-s)Du(x)) \ ds dt = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(tDu(x+h) + (1-t)Du(x))  \ dt
$$

I am not sure to can put $s$ on the limits of integration, but maybe it can be correct. I know that I could introduce another variable $t$, but I need the formula in this way.

Comment: This needs some serious work. You shouldn't use the same variable twice when integrating.

Comment: is $D$ a constant or a differential operator? Also you shouldn't put the variable your integrating in a limit

Comment: D is a differential operator

Comment: Is now the formula correct?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \int_0^1 \int_0^s 
            \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial s\partial s}F(sDu(x+h) + (1-s)Du(x)) ds ds \\
  &= \int_0^1 \left[
           \int_0^s \frac{\partial}{\partial s}
                    \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial s} F(sDu(x+h) + (1-s)Du(x)) \right] ds
              \right] ds \\
  &= \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} F(sDu(x+h) + (1-s)Du(x)) ds\\
  &= F(sDu(x+h) + (1-s)Du(x)) \bigg|_{s=0}^{s=1} \\
  &= F(Du(x+h)) - F(Du(x))
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Yeah I mean this. Is  that correct right?

Comment: @Fil I think so